# Integrating a function over the interval formed by the largest two real roots of a cubic equation

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic

**Description of the problem**: Suppose I have a depressed cubic equation $-x^3+p^2x-q^2=0$ under the condition (*the local max is larger than zero and local min is less than zero*)

$$-\frac{2}{3\sqrt 3} |p|^3 <q^2< \frac{2}{3\sqrt 3} |p|^3 \tag{*}$$

so that it has three real roots $x_1(p,q)<x_2(p,q)<x_3(p,q)$ and over the interval $(x_2(p,q),x_3(p,q))$ formed by the largest two roots of it, the function $-x^3+p^2x-q^2$ has negative value.

Now I want to evaluate the integral:

$$I:=\int_{x_2}^{x_3}\frac{-x^3+p^2x-q^2}{x^4}~dx$$

and get a expression in terms of $p,q$ **without the imaginary unit $i$**.

**My attempts and questions:**

(1) The command

```
Reduce[-x^3 + p^2 x - q^2 == 0, x]
```

Only returns three roots (with imaginary unit $i$) and it is hard to tell which two are the largest.

(2) The condition $-\frac{2}{3\sqrt 3} |p|^3 <q^2< \frac{2}{3\sqrt 3} |p|^3 \tag{*}$ probably means nothing to Mathematica ? No matter it is satisfied or not, we always have imaginary expressions in $x_2,x_3$, and $I$ as well. How do we tell mathematica there is such a condition and "force" $I$ to be real?

Answer (score 3):

Let's express $p^2$ and $q^2$ in terms of roots $x_2$ and $x_3$:

```
rel = SolveAlways[-(x - x1) (x - x2) (x - x3) == -x^3 + p2 x - q2, x] /.
{p2 -> p^2, q2 -> q^2} // Flatten
```

> ```
> {p^2 -> x2^2 + x2 x3 + x3^2, q^2 -> x2 x3 (x2 + x3), x1 -> -x2 - x3}
> ```

Our assumptions imply that `x1 < 0 < x2 < x3`, since at `x == 0` we have `-x^3 + p^2 x - q^2 == -q^2 < 0` if `q` is real and `x1 + x2 + x3 == 0` because coeficcient of `x^2` vanishes. Moreover between `x2` and `x3` the polynomial is positive `-x^3 + p^2 x - q^2 > 0` Now we can exploit `Integrate` supressing generating conditions

```
intg = Integrate[-((x - x1) (x - x2) (x - x3))/x^4, {x, x2, x3}, 
                 Assumptions -> x1 + x2 + x3 == 0 && x1 < 0 < x2 < x3, 
                 GenerateConditions -> False]
```

> ```
> -((x2 - x3) (x2 + x3) (x2^2 + x2 x3 + x3^2))/(6 x2^2 x3^2) + Log[x2] - Log[x3]
> ```

Comparing relations `rel` with `intg` we can rewrite it as

```
int = (x3 - x2)/(6 x3^3 x2^3) p^2 q^2 - Log[x3/x2];
```

indeed:

```
Simplify[ intg - int /. rel, 0 < x2 < x3]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

Condition (2) means that there are three distinct roots, under our assumptions it means that the discriminant doesn't vanish:

```
Discriminant[x^3 - p^2 x + q^2, x]
```

> ```
> 4 p^6 - 27 q^4
> ```

The issue with apparently complex expressions for reals roots is called [Casus irreducibilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis)